# Include (../x.php) doesn't work on my Linux server why?

Tags: php, include

In my Xampp I can do :

```
require_once('../myFile.php');
```

And it works.

When I upload the file that do the require_once, it doesn't work.

Here is the error on the server:

```
Warning: require_once(../myFile.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/public_html/yyyy/testinclude.php on line 11

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '../myFile.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxx/public_html/yyyy/testinclude.php on line 11
```

Any idea?

Comment: since you're on Linux, filename is case sensitive. check to make sure the case of the filename is the same

Comment: That was the issue! Andrew Moore wrote it and I accepted it :) Thanks Yada

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible reason why its not working is that your file-casing isn't exactly the same.

In UNIX, file paths are case-sensitive. This is not the case in WIN. So, if you are including `../myFile.php`, your file must be name `myFile.php`, not `myfile.php`.

---

Also, `include` are always including files according to the **current path**. Consider these two files.

```
/home/xxx/public_html/first.php

<?php include('dir/second.php'); ?>

/home/xxx/public_html/dir/second.php

<?php include('third.php'); ?>
```

When running `first.php`, the second file will include `/home/xxx/public_html/third.php`.

When running `dir/second.php` directly, it will include `/home/xxx/public_html/dir/third.php`.

If your include must always be relative to the current file, use the following:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/third.php');
```

Using the above code fragment, `dir/second.php` will always include `/home/xxx/public_html/dir/third.php` regardless of the current directory.

Comment: YOU GOT IT!!!!! +1 and the answer! WOW nice job dude the name of the file was about 35 characters long and one 'b' was there instead of 'B' in the middle of it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If `myFile.php` doesn't exist in directory `public_html`, then it won't work.

If you want it to look in the same directory as you, try `require_once('./myFile.php')`

Comment: Not true, he is including `../myFile.php`, therefore the file must reside in `/home/xxx/public_html/`

Comment: it does exist... I told in the question that it works on the Windows Machine and the file on the server is used in the yyyy directory...

Comment: Andrew, I don't see the mistake? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `myFile.php` file relative to your `testinclude.php` file?

If you're requiring it in `../` then `myFile.php` needs to be one level higher than `testinclude.php` (i.e. in `/home/xxx/public_html/`)